# Once I have an F-Algebra, can I define Foldable and Traversable in terms of it?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, recursion-schemes

I have defined an *F-Algebra*, as per Bartosz Milewski's articles ([one](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2013/06/10/understanding-f-algebras/), [two](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/02/28/f-algebras/)):

*(This is not to say my code is an exact embodiment of Bartosz's ideas, it's merely my limited understanding of them, and any faults are mine alone.)*

```
module Algebra where

data Expr a = Branch [a] | Leaf Int

instance Functor Expr where
    fmap f (Branch xs) = Branch (fmap f xs)
    fmap _ (Leaf   i ) = Leaf    i

newtype Fix a = Fix { unFix :: a (Fix a) }

branch = Fix . Branch
leaf   = Fix . Leaf

-- | This is an example algebra.
evalSum (Branch xs) = sum xs
evalSum (Leaf   i ) =     i

cata f = f . fmap (cata f) . unFix
```

I can now do pretty much anything I want about it, for example, sum the leaves:

```
λ cata evalSum $ branch [branch [leaf 1, leaf 2], leaf 3]
6
```

This is a contrived example that I made up specifically for this question, but I actually tried some less trivial things (such as evaluating and simplifying polynomials with any number of variables) and it works like a charm. One may indeed fold and replace any parts of a structure as one runs a *catamorphism* through, with a suitably chosen *algebra*. So, I am pretty sure an F-Algebra subsumes a Foldable, and it even appears to subsume Traversable as well.

**Now, can I define Foldable / Traversable instances in terms of an F-Algebra?**

It seems to me that I cannot.

- I can only run a catamorphism on an *initial algebra*, which is a nullary type constructor. And the algebra I give it has a type `a b -> b` rather than `a -> b`, that is to say, there is a *functional dependency* between the "in" and "out" type.
- I don't see an `Algebra a => Foldable a` anywhere in type signatures. If this is not done, it must be impossible.

It seems to me that I cannot define `Foldable` in terms of an F-Algebra for the reason that an `Expr` must for that be a `Functor` in two variables: one for *carrier*, another for *values*, and then a `Foldable` in the second. So, it may be that a *bifunctor* is more suitable. And we can construct an F-Algebra with a bifunctor as well:

```
module Algebra2 where

import Data.Bifunctor

data Expr a i = Branch [a] | Leaf i

instance Bifunctor Expr where
    bimap f _ (Branch xs) = Branch (fmap f xs)
    bimap _ g (Leaf   i ) = Leaf   (g i)

newtype Fix2 a i = Fix2 { unFix2 :: a (Fix2 a i) i }

branch = Fix2 . Branch
leaf   = Fix2 . Leaf

evalSum (Branch xs) = sum xs
evalSum (Leaf   i ) =     i

cata2 f g = f . bimap (cata2 f g) g . unFix2
```

It runs like this:

```
λ cata2 evalSum (+1) $ branch [branch [leaf 1, leaf 2], leaf 3]
9
```

But I still can't define a Foldable. It would have type like this:

```
instance Foldable \i -> Expr (Fix2 Expr i) i where ...
```

Unfortunately, one doesn't get lambda abstractions on types, and there's no way to put an implied type variable in two places at once.

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An F-algebra defines a recipe for evaluating a single level of a recursive data structure, after you have evaluated all the children. `Foldable` defines a way of evaluating a (not necessarily recursive) data structure, provided you know how to convert values stored in it to elements of a monoid.

To implement `foldMap` for a recursive data structure, you may start by defining an algebra, whose carrier is a monoid. You would define how to convert a leaf to a monoidal value. Then, assuming that all children of a node were evaluated to monoidal values, you'd define a way to combine them within a node. Once you've defined such an algebra, you can run a catamorphism to evaluate `foldMap` for the whole tree.

So the answer to your question is that to make a `Foldable` instance for a fixed-point data structure, you have to define an appropriate algebra whose carrier is a monoid.

Edit: Here's an implementation of Foldable:

```
data Expr e a = Branch [a] | Leaf e

newtype Ex e = Ex { unEx :: Fix (Expr e) }

evalM :: Monoid m => (e -> m) -> Algebra (Expr e) m
evalM _ (Branch xs) = mconcat xs
evalM f (Leaf   i ) = f i

instance Foldable (Ex) where
  foldMap f = cata (evalM f) . unEx

tree :: Ex Int
tree = Ex $ branch [branch [leaf 1, leaf 2], leaf 3]

x = foldMap Sum tree
```

Implementing `Traversable` as a catamorphism is a little more involved because you want the result to be not just a summary--it must contain the complete reconstructed data structure. The carrier of the algebra must therefore be the type of the final result of `traverse`, which is `(f (Fix (Expr b)))`, where `f` is `Applicative`.

```
tAlg :: Applicative f => (e -> f b) -> Algebra (Expr e) (f (Fix (Expr b)))
```

Here's this algebra:

```
tAlg g (Leaf e)    = leaf   <$> g e
tAlg _ (Branch xs) = branch <$> sequenceA xs
```

And this is how you implement `traverse`:

```
instance Traversable Ex where
  traverse g = fmap Ex . cata (tAlg g) . unEx
```

The superclass of `Traversable` is a `Functor`, so you need to show that the fixed-point data structure is a functor. You can do it by implementing a simple algebra and running a catamorphism over it:

```
fAlg :: (a -> b) -> Algebra (Expr a) (Fix (Expr b))
fAlg g (Leaf e) = leaf (g e)
fAlg _ (Branch es) = branch es

instance Functor Ex where
  fmap g = Ex . cata (fAlg g) . unEx
```

(Michael Sloan helped me write this code.)

Comment: Yes, but can I make it adhere to the type signature for `foldMap`? I believe my `evalSum` is the algebra you're talking about, but it kind of doesn't help.

Comment: Oh. I didn't think of making an algebra parametric.

Comment: I also added the implementation of `Traversable`.

Answer (score 4):

It's very nice, that you used `Bifunctor`. Using `Bifunctor` of a base functor (`Expr`) to define `Functor` on a fixpoint (`Fix Expr`).
That approach generalises to `Bifoldable` and `Bitraversable` (they are in `base` now) too.

Let's see how this would like using [`recursion-schemes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes).
It looks a bit different, as there we define normal recursive type,
say `Tree e`, and also its base functor: `Base (Tree e) = TreeF e a` with two functions:
`project :: Tree e -> TreeF e (Tree e)` and `embed :: TreeF e (Tree e) -> Tree e`.
The recursion machinery is derivable using *TemplateHaskell*:

Note that we have `Base (Fix f) = f` (`project = unFix`, `embed = Fix`),
therefore we can use `refix` convert `Tree e` to `Fix (TreeF e)` and back. But
we don't need to use `Fix`, as we able to `cata` `Tree` directly!

First includes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies, DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable #-}
import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH

import Data.Bifunctor
import Data.Bifoldable
import Data.Bitraversable
```

Then the data:

```
data Tree e = Branch [Tree e] | Leaf e deriving Show

-- data TreeF e r = BranchF [r] | LeafF e
-- instance Traversable (TreeF e)
-- instance Foldable (TreeF e)
-- instance Functor (TreeF e)
makeBaseFunctor ''Tree
```

Now as we have machinery in place, we can have catamorphisms

```
cata :: Recursive t => (Base t a -> a) -> t -> a
cata f = c where c = f . fmap c . project
```

or (which we will need later)

```
cataBi :: (Recursive t, Bifunctor p, Base t ~ p x) => (p x a -> a) -> t -> a
cataBi f = c where c = f . second c . project
```

First a `Functor` instance. The `Bifunctor` instance for `TreeF` is as OP has written,
note how `Functor` falls out by itself.

```
instance Bifunctor TreeF where
    bimap f _ (LeafF e)    = LeafF (f e)
    bimap _ g (BranchF xs) = BranchF (fmap g xs)

instance Functor Tree where
    fmap f = cata (embed . bimap f id)
```

Not surprisingly, `Foldable` for fixpoint can be defined in terms of `Bifoldable` of base
functor:

```
instance Bifoldable TreeF where
    bifoldMap f _ (LeafF e)    = f e
    bifoldMap _ g (BranchF xs) = foldMap g xs

instance Foldable Tree where
    foldMap f = cata (bifoldMap f id)
```

And finally `Traversable`:

```
instance Bitraversable TreeF where
    bitraverse f _ (LeafF e)    = LeafF <$> f e
    bitraverse _ g (BranchF xs) = BranchF <$> traverse g xs

instance Traversable Tree where
    traverse f = cata (fmap embed . bitraverse f id)
```

As you can see the definitions are very straight forward and follow similarish
pattern.

Indeed we can define `traverse`-like function for every fix-point which base
functor is `Bitraversable`.

```
traverseRec
    :: ( Recursive t, Corecursive s, Applicative f
       , Base t ~ base a, Base s ~ base b, Bitraversable base)
    => (a -> f b) -> t -> f s
traverseRec f = cataBi (fmap embed . bitraverse f id)
```

Here we use `cataBi` to make type-signature prettier: no `Functor (base b)` as
it's "implied" by `Bitraversable base`. Btw, that's a one nice function as its
type signature is three times longer than the implementation).

To conclude, I must mention that `Fix` in Haskell is not perfect:
We use the last argument to fix base-functor:

```
Fix :: (* -> *) -> * -- example: Tree e ~ Fix (TreeF e)
```

Thus Bartosz needs to define `Ex` in his answer to make kinds align,
however it would be nicer to fix on the first argument:

```
Fix :: (* -> k) -> k -- example: Tree e = Fix TreeF' e
```

where `data TreeF' a e = LeafF' e | BranchF' [a]`, i.e. `TreeF` with indexes
flipped. That way we could have `Functor (Fix b)` in terms of `Bifunctor f`,
`Bifunctor (Fix b)` in terms of (non-existing in common libraries) `Trifunctor` etc.

You can read about my failed attempts about that and Edward Kmett's comments
on the issue in https://github.com/ekmett/recursion-schemes/pull/23

Comment: Oh, I never thought of giving separate names to what, as I now discover, would be called "base functor" and "fixpoint". It was like one murky entanglement in my imagination. Feels much more comfortable now.