# Granted a traversable F-Algebra, is it possible to have a catamorphism over an applicative algebra?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, catamorphism

I have this F-Algebra ([introduced in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488021)), and I want to cast an effectful algebra upon it. Through desperate trial, I managed to put together a monadic catamorphism that works. I wonder if it may be generalized to an applicative, and if not, why.

This is how I defined `Traversable`:

```
instance Traversable Expr where
    traverse f (Branch xs) = fmap Branch $ traverse f xs
    traverse f (Leaf   i ) = pure $ Leaf i
```

This is the monadic catamorphism:

```
type AlgebraM a f b = a b -> f b

cataM :: (Monad f, Traversable a) => AlgebraM a f b -> Fix a -> f b
cataM f x = f =<< (traverse (cataM f) . unFix $ x)
```

And this is how it works:

```
λ let printAndReturn x = print x >> pure x
λ cataM (printAndReturn . evalSum) $ branch [branch [leaf 1, leaf 2], leaf 3]
1
2
3
3
6
6
```

My idea now is that I could rewrite like this:

```
cataA :: (Applicative f, Traversable a) => AlgebraM a f b -> Fix a -> f b
cataA f x = do
    subtree <- traverse (cataA f) . unFix $ x
    value <- f subtree
    return value
```

Unfortunately, `value` here depends on `subtree` and, [according to a paper on applicative do-notation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/desugaring-haskell-haskell16.pdf), in such case we cannot desugar to Applicative. It seems like there's no way around this; we need a monad to float up from the depths of nesting.

Is it true? Can I safely conclude that only flat structures can be folded with applicative effects alone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I safely conclude that only flat structures can be folded with applicative effects alone?

You can say that again! After all, "flattening nested structures" is exactly what makes a monad a monad, rather than `Applicative` which can only combine adjacent structures. Compare (a version of) the signatures of the two abstractions:

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
    pure :: a -> f a
    (<.>) :: f a -> f b -> f (a, b)

class Applicative m => Monad m where
    join :: m (m a) -> m a
```

What `Monad` adds to `Applicative` is the ability to flatten *nested* `m`s into one `m`. That's why `[]`'s `join` is `concat`. `Applicative` only lets you smash together heretofore-unrelated `f`s.

It's no coincidence that the free monad's `Free` constructor contains a whole `f` full of `Free f`s, whereas the free applicative's `Ap` constructor only contains one `Ap f`.

```
data Free f a = Return a | Free (f (Free f a))
data Ap f a where
    Pure :: a -> Ap f a
    Cons :: f a -> Ap f b -> Ap f (a, b)
```

Hopefully that gives you some intuition as to why you should expect that it's not possible to fold a tree using an `Applicative`.

Let's play a little *type tennis* to see how it shakes out. We want to write

```
cataA :: (Traversable f, Applicative m) => (f a -> m a) -> Fix f -> m a
cataA f (Fix xs) = _
```

We have `xs :: f (Fix f)` and a `Traversable` for `f`. My first instinct here is to `traverse` the `f` to fold the contained subtrees:

```
cataA f (Fix xs) = _ $ traverse (cataA f) xs
```

The hole now has a goal type of `m (f a) -> m a`. Since there's an `f :: f a -> m a` knocking about, let's try going under the `m` to convert the contained `f`s:

```
cataA f (Fix xs) = _ $ fmap f $ traverse (cataA f) xs
```

Now we have a goal type of `m (m a) -> m a`, which is `join`. So you do need a `Monad` after all.

Comment: This is some spectacular *type tennis* proficiency. Can you advise a reading with a more extensive and rigorous treatment of such matters?

Comment: @Kindaro hmm, I don't think I do know of anywhere to find a full proof, sorry. I'm speaking merely from a broad understanding of how monads differ from applicatives, not from a rigorous formal basis. You might have fun writing such a proof yourself - I expect it'd be proved by contradiction ("assume `cataA` can be implemented ... thus a contradiction").