# Given a Nothing, how do I construct values of type RWST env log state Maybe value?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Suppose I want a computation that evaluates expressions with variables. I would like it to look variables up in the env passed to its runner, and also have some kind of state and a log. I take an [algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488021), pepper it with `RWS` and I'm done.

Except that `lookup` returns `Maybe`.

So I need a monad stack.

```
λ type EvalA = MaybeT (RWS () () ()) ()
λ runRWS (runMaybeT (MaybeT (return (Just ())) :: EvalA )) () ()
(Just (),(),())
λ runRWS (runMaybeT (MaybeT (return Nothing) :: EvalA )) () ()
(Nothing,(),())
```

So far so good. But the type is somewhat messy: a transformer on top of a transformer on top of `Identity`. Why not flip this.

```
λ type EvalB = RWST () () () Maybe ()
λ runRWST (return () :: EvalB) () ()
Just ((),(),())
λ runRWST (Nothing :: EvalB) () ()

<interactive>:12:10: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Maybe a0’ with ‘RWST () () () Maybe ()’
      Expected type: EvalB
        Actual type: Maybe a0
    ..........
λ -- ...?
```

Putting aside that having a `Nothing` plus a log is better than having a `Nothing` alone, how can I obtain a `Nothing` from `EvalB`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift), which is the fundamental operation monad transformers support.

```
ghci> runRWST (lift Nothing) () ()
Nothing
```

But also be careful doing this kind of swapping.  `Maybe` does not commute with `RWS`.  In fact, it doesn't commute with any of them!  For example:

```
WriterT w Maybe a
  ≃ Maybe (a, w)
```

but

```
MaybeT (Writer w a)
  ≃ Writer w (Maybe a)
  ≃ (Maybe a, w)
```

In the former, with `Maybe` as the base monad, a `Nothing` value erases the writer's log -- all you get is failure.  In the latter, with `Writer` as the base, the computation can fail yet still produce a value in the log.

A very good exercise is to do this with each of [`Reader`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html), [`Writer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html), and [`State`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html), and find a computation that is representable in one of `MaybeT m`, `mT Maybe` but not the other.

Comment: Thanks. I bet I tried putting `lift` in random places before asking.